# How to validate the all parametes by using XSD against validation

Tags: xsd-validation

How to validate the all mandatory parameters at one time.I want to display all mandatory parameters not entered in user  .For Example I have 4 parameters username,pwd,phno,address.

If the user not provided the information of two parameters like pwd and address.

By using the XSD against validation concept,It throwing the SAX Exception on PWD.but it not showing the exception on Adress as well.

Condition:
1.Input format may jsonformat,xml,or any thing.

Please share information.
I have not found concrete information from this site.